# regex is not working as expected

Tags: regex

i am using this regex exp `/[^\p{L}\s-]/` to capture strange characters.

The problem is that regex match this words for example:

```
Santarém (city name)
or 
Constançia (city name)
```

so i need to block symbols like `"#$#%/*&/!` but no the ´` Ç or ^~ -

thanks

Comment: which language are you writing code in? Would help knowing. I think in general however you should list all characters you want to treat as letter.

Comment: So the issue is that you want to use regex to capture midly strange characters, but not overtly strange characters? At least the criteria is well defined, this should be cake.

Comment: [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) provides a fairly extensive list of various regex tokens specifically for unicode (\p{*})...maybe there is something there that will suit your as yet unspecified requirements?

Comment: \p{L} should match them as stated in http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php probably is some build option of the PCRE library in the php you're using that's not supporting correctly unicode strings.

Comment: Just FYI, there is at least one town in England which has an exclamation mark in it's name (Westard Ho! -- look it up if you don't believe me). So if you're looking to allow characters that can be in town names, you need to allow that. Not sure what else is out there, but when it comes to validating names, less validation is usually best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solve my problem

thanks

```
[^A-Za-z0-9-áàçéâãôó]|(\d+)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how the city names are stored, but the marks could be stored as separate unicode elements, in which case you need to include the \p{M} set in your regex (as per http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)